# Using a csv file to make a dictionary of stock prices with date as the key

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files, stock

Basically I am using a csv file that has daily stock prices for apple I got from yahoo finance. I have the user enter a file name and use it to go through and print stock prices. I am having trouble with the first function

example output

```
[{'Date': '2020-01-02', 'Open': '74.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'}, {'Date': '2020-01-03', 'Open': '74.287498', 'High': '75.144997', 'Low': '74.125000', 'Close': '74.357498', 'Adj Close': '73.610840', 'Volume': '146322800'}... ]
```

Code attempt:

```
import csv

def createdict(file_name):
  perfect_dict=[]
  with open('apple.dat') as f:
    file_name = list(csv.file_name(f))
  
    for row in file_name[1:]:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict["Date"] = row[0]
        temp_dict["Open"] = row[1]
        temp_dict["High"] = row[2]
        temp_dict["Low"] = row[3]
        temp_dict["Close"] = row[4]
        temp_dict["Adj Close"] =row[5]
        temp_dict["Volume"] = row[6]
        perfect_dict.append(temp_dict)
  return perfect_dict

def main():
  print("Welcome to the Stock Price Program")
  print()
  file_name=input("Enter the data file name: ")

main()
```

Comment: sorry, the question is not clear. so you got a list of dict like this `{'Date': '2020-01-02', 'Open': '74.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'},` would not be easy that you load your csv as pandas dataframe? , what is the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: I have to print the open, high, low, close, adj price, and volume prices for a user entered date

Comment: thanks. so there are ways to achieve this. so for example - the user entered 2020-01-02, you want to look at this date's data in your csv file?  or want to make a call to yahoo finance to get the record for this date(not sure if you have an API for this)?

Comment: yes I have a csv file that holds the data called apple.dat

Comment: thank you. provided the answer, I hope will be helpful.

Comment: Your `main` function never calls `create_dict`

Comment: @simpleApp can you check the edit, I made a createdict function and a main function.

Comment: @tripleee I add a function called  dictionary=createdict(file_name) but get an error that says AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'file_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be many more ways, but two ways listed here.

**Data Setup**

```
# Test Data , sorry did not had csv, so this is starting point
my_csv_data=[{'Date': '2020-01-02', 'Open': '74.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'},
          {'Date': '2020-01-03', 'Open': '75.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'},
          {'Date': '2020-01-04', 'Open': '76.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'}]
```

**Query date** the date on which search needs to be made

```
input_date='2020-01-04' # date the system received for query (1)
```

```
# 1st option
for each in my_csv_data:
    if each['Date'] == input_date: # find record matching with the query date
        for each_key in each:
            print(f"{each_key}:{each[each_key]}")
```

output:

```
Date:2020-01-04
Open:76.059998
High:75.150002
Low:73.797501
Close:75.087502
Adj Close:74.333511
Volume:135480400
```

2nd option, using pandas.

```
# 2nd option
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(my_csv_data)
df_result=df[df["Date"] == input_date] # find the record for the query date
for each in df_result:
    print(each,(df_result[each].tolist()[0])) # loop and reformat for printing
```

**output:**

```
Date 2020-01-04
Open 76.059998
High 75.150002
Low 73.797501
Close 75.087502
Adj Close 74.333511
Volume 135480400
```

Comment: I tried the first option. I am having trouble implementing them as functions

Comment: may I know what is the trouble? will try to help further.

Comment: can you check the edit, I made a createdict function and a main function.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this faster using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('apple.dat') #read CSV file into a dataframe df
perfect_dict = list(df.T.to_dict().values())
print (perfect_dict)
```

Note - You variable named `perfect_dict` is actually a list of dict objects.

Output:

```
[{'Date': '2020-04-27', 'Open': 70.449997, 'High': 71.135002, 'Low': 69.987503, 'Close': 70.792503, 'Adj Close': 70.247971, 'Volume': 117087600}, {'Date': '2020-04-28', 'Open': 71.269997, 'High': 71.457497, 'Low': 69.550003, 'Close': 69.644997, 'Adj Close': 69.109299, 'Volume': 112004800}, {'Date': '2020-04-29', 'Open': 71.182503, 'High': 72.417503, 'Low': 70.972504, 'Close': 71.932503, 'Adj Close': 71.379196, 'Volume': 137280800}]
```

Comment: I do not think I can use the pandas because I need to print the prices based on a user's entered date

Comment: That's no reason to avoid Pandas, but it's probably severe overkill for this simple tasks for other reasons.